# setting java_home weird error

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu, java-home

I have an ubuntu machine..

In my ~/.bashrc I have set java_home as

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

but still when i do

```
$which java
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/java
```

what can be the reason?
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? There are is the `update-alternatives` command for example, to use a different version of java

Comment: have you logged out and logged in again? the .bashrc is read only once at each login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `echo $JAVA_HOME` and `echo $PATH` and you will see that they have been set correctly. The problem is you are asking the shell where is the executable java and it's not looking at the JAVA_HOME variable.

If you've just edited your .bashrc, you will need to manually run the file, or login to your shell again to pick up the changes.

You have 2 choices:

1. Refer to the specific jdk you want to use on a per use basis
2. Update the default java using update-alternatives as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java)